# How to use a self-defined function in the Manipulate function

Tags: manipulate

This is what I want

```
Manipulate[ Plot[ Which[h < a, 1 - 1.5 h/a + 0.5 (h/a)^3, h >= a, 0], {h, 0, 8}],
            {a, 5, 10}]
```

Is it possible to rewrite it as something like the following?

```
f[h_] := Which[ h < a, 1 - 1.5 h/a + 0.5 (h/a)^3, h >= a, 0];
Manipulate[ Plot[ f[h], {h, 0, 8}], {a, 5, 10}]
```

Seems it doesn't work for me. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Notice that `a` has a different colour inside and out of the manipulate. one a is global and another is local. `Manipulate[Dynamic@Plot[f[h], {h, 0, 8}], {a, 5, 10}, 
 Initialization :> {f[h_] := 
    Which[h < a, 1 - 1.5 h/a + 0.5 (h/a)^3, h >= a, 0]}]` ...or alternatively make `f` a function of both `h` and `a` and then u don't need the `Dynamic`

Comment: I realized what you were trying to do. This was my solution `f[h_, a_] := Which[h < a, 1 - 1.5 h/a + 0.5 (h/a)^3, h >= a, 0]; Manipulate[Plot[f[h, a], {h, 0, 8}], {a, 5, 10}]` but I see that @MikeHoneychurch has already mentioned it.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[h_] := Which[h < a, 1 - 1.5 h/a + 0.5 (h/a)^3, h >= a, 0];
With[{g = f[h]},
 Manipulate[Plot[g, {h, 0, 8}], {a, 5, 10}]]
```

also

```
f[h_] := Which[h < a, 1 - 1.5 h/a + 0.5 (h/a)^3, h >= a, 0];
Manipulate[Plot[f[h] /. a -> b, {h, 0, 8}], {b, 5, 10}]
```